# Follow shortened url then return JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I would like to know if I somehow can browse to i.e http://avatars.io/twitter/billgates 
and then store the url we got redirected to * in a variable.

- which in this case will be http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558109954561679360/j1f9DiJi_normal.jpeg

Using JavaScript and without the user noticing.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to change a few things in the final url before storing it.

Comment: Once the user left your site, or opened a new tab, no, you can't. What you can do, however, is create an iframe with that `src`, wait for it to load and get the new `src`.

Comment: This will depend on the environment executing the code and the URLs being requested. Using client-side code in a web page, access to that information will be restricted by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The endpoints can give permission to access, but that's up to the owners to decide.

Comment: @blex The src will not change. I need the redirect url. Can I somehow use ajax post and then get the url back?